# Выйгрыш при использовании UNION в Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Получу ли я существенный выйгрыш, если вместо двух запросов **SELECT** буду делать один запрос объединяя их **UNION**?

Comment: "Получу ли я **существенный** выйгрыш" - нет, не получите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если рассматривать в Mysql, два подряд `select` отработают с той же скоростью, что и с `union`. С точки зрения php, несущественно дольше. Связано это с тем, что php будет дважды обращаться к mysql.